APS - Return Company Name With Contract
I'm calling the contracts endpoint and in return I receive the companyId and companyUid, however, the companyName always returns null. Below is an excerpt of the returned payload.
"code": "283100-SUB",
"budgetIds": [
    "ea15c008-f9d3-48eb-b8ac-5a02637dedb9",
],
"status": "sent",
"subStatus": null,
"paymentDue": null,
"paymentDueType": "afterStart",
"companyId": "420681482",
"companyUid": "01bdd6ed-0e56-4f34-a753-a0b5c83269ec",
"companyName": null,
"type": "Subcontract",

Can we get the response to return the CompanyName for the contract so we don't have to make an extra call?
